# Why do we mask input tokens for the decoder in a transformer?

Tags: machine-learning, transformers

I am currently trying to understand how the Transformer Architecture created by Vaswani et al. in 2017 works. Regarding this I have problems understanding the training process of the decoder.
[image: Transformer]

If the output of the Decoder is sequentially input back into the Decoder, why is there a need to mask tokens that are in a position right of the token in the output of the decoder? Shouldn't these tokens not have been generated yet and therefore not be relevant to mask?

Thanks

Comment: The "multi-head" part of the question is a red herring: it doesn't affect the answer if it's simply single-head attention. You mask to avoid reading from the parts that haven't been filled with usable data. The space is already allocated, but you shouldn't read from it until you put in good values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence we feed to the decoder always has to be the same length.
So when we feed the decoder a sequence the sequence must be "full-length". In this kind of transformer the generation of tokens, happens by the decoder always predicting the next token, based on the already generated tokens.
However, because we have to use as input a complete sequence and not only what has been generated so far, the Decoder could "look" at the words that are right of the already generated tokens. In order to avoid this everything right f the token that is to be predicted will be masked.

Here is an example

Complete Sentence:

`[SOS] [I] [like] [hot] [chocolate] [EOS] [PAD] [PAD]`

Step One the Decoder aims to predict the `[I]`based on the `[SOS]` token and the output of the Encoder

`[SOS] [MASK] [MASK] [MASK] [MAKS] [MASK] [MASK] [MASK]`

In the second step, as he already has predicted the `[I]`, so now based on the first two tokens he aims to predict the 3rd. So the input for the decoder will be.

`[SOS] [I] [MASK] [MASK] [MAKS] [MASK] [MASK] [MASK]`

and so on:

`[SOS] [I] [like] [MASK] [MAKS] [MASK] [MASK] [MASK]`

Comment: Ok thanks. So the maximum length is probably predetermined and these [PAD] Token are placeholders if the sequence we generate is shorter than the maximum length?

Comment: Yes exactly, so you usually would find the longest sentence in your data set, and bring all other sentences to the same length by using padding tokens.